# Describe as explicitly as you can all terms in the canonical decomposition of the function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ as $r \mapsto e^{2\pi ir}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R/ {\sim}$ as $r \mapsto [r]_\sim$ where $\sim$ on $\mathbb R$ is given by $r' \sim r'' \leftrightarrow f(r') = f(r'').$

$\widetilde f: \mathbb R/{\sim} \to \operatorname{im} f$ given as $\widetilde f([r]_\sim) = f(r).$

$f: \operatorname{im}f \to \mathbb C$ given as $[r]_\sim \mapsto e^{2\pi ir}$.

Is that what we are being asked to do?

Comment: Unfortunately the Math.SE community only knows what you are being asked to do by virtue of your sharing that knowledge with us.  Here the tag `elementary-set-theory` does not seem to accord with the mapping of reals to the complex unit circle, as indicated in the title, and you introduce a different map $f$ in the body of the Question.

Comment: The \sim symbol $\text{“}\sim\text{''}$ is treated by the software a a binary operation symbol, so that in expressions like $a\sim b$ there is some space to its left and right.  That spacing is inappropriate in expressions like $\displaystyle\mathbb R/{\sim}$, and it can be avoided by coding it as \mathbb R/{\sim}. If you don't do that, then it looks like this: $\displaystyle\mathbb R/\sim$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: [Here is a capture from my textbook](http://s3.postimg.org/nik2jhn2b/Capture.png)

Comment: Typo: I meant "binary relation symbol" rather than "binary operation symbol". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Is the context here a group homomorphism, e.g. from additive group $\mathbb{R}$ to the multiplicative group of the complex unit circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\mathbb R \longrightarrow \hspace{-14pt} \longrightarrow (\mathbb R/{\sim}) \overset \sim \longrightarrow (\operatorname{im} f = \{ z\in \mathbb C : |z|=1\}) \hookrightarrow \mathbb C
$$

Since $r\mapsto e^{2\pi r i}$ is periodic with period $1$, the relation $a\sim b$ on $\mathbb R$ means $a-b$ is an integer.  You can show that that is an equivalence relation.

The space $\mathbb R/{\sim}$ is the set of all equivalence classes.  Then $1/8$ (think of a $45^\circ$ angle) becomes the same as $9/8$ (a $360^\circ+45^\circ = 405^\circ$ angle). The mapping from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R/{\sim}$ takes a number like $9/8$ and maps it to the equivalence class it belongs to, in effect forgetting whether it's $1/8$ or $9/8$ or $17/8$ or some other point where the sine and cosine are the same as they are at that point. I wrote "onto" rather than "into" because no equivalence class is omitted.

The mapping from $\mathbb R/{\sim}$ to $\operatorname{im} f$ goes from $\mathbb R/{\sim}$ the circle $\{z\in\mathbb C: |z|=1\}$.  That circle is $\operatorname{im} f$.  It takes the equivalence class to which $1/12$ belongs (and so does $1+1/12$, and so does $2+1/12$, and so does $-1+1/12$, etc) to the point
$$
e^{2 \pi i \left( \frac{1}{12} \right)} = \cos\frac\pi 6 + i\sin\frac\pi6 = \frac{\sqrt3}2 + i\frac 1 2.
$$
That point is on the circle $|z|=1$, which is the image of $f$.  This mapping is both one-to-one and onto.  It is one-to-one because it always takes different equivalence classes of numbers to different points on the circle.  It is onto because every point on the circle is the image of some equivance class.

Finally, the mapping from $\operatorname{im} f = \{ z\in\mathbb C: |z|=1\}$ to $\mathbb C$ just takes each point to itself.  It is one-to-one.  It is not onto because not every point in $\mathbb C$ is the image of some point on the circle.  Only those points in $\mathbb C$ that are on the circle have pre-images under this function.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know much about complex numbers. I hope it's ok if I ask trivial questions. Why do we define $a \sim b$ the way we do and why is $imf$ a circle?

Comment: @user279911 :  I missed the factor of $2\pi$; now I've revised my answer accordingly. The function $r\mapsto e^{2\pi ir}$ is equal to $r \mapsto \cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)$. That's what you need to know about complex numbers here.  It maps $r$ to a point on a circle. ${}\qquad{}$